# Leer un XMLtype con pl/sql

Tags: base-de-datos, xml, oracle

Tengo una función que recibe por parametro un xml, necesito quedarme solo con una parte, y devolver ese "nuevo xml". Entiendo se realiza con la función Extract pero no me estaría funcionando. 
Me da error: ORA-00932 incosistent datatypes: expected CHAR got - 
Obviamente ya los busque y cambie los tipos de los parametros, etc, pero no hay caso, no me sale. 
Lo que necesito como salida es solo la porción de xml dentro de los nodos evento, no los datos si no todo el xml en si. Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo la manera en la que trabajado con los XML es extrayéndolo de la BD y luego procesando el XML nodo a nodo. En el caso que comentas, para quedarte con todo lo que hay dentro del nodo evento sería algo así:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (VL_XL_XML, '/params/evento', VL_C_ESPACIO) INTO VL_XL_EVENTO FROM DUAL;
```

Donde VL_XL_XML es una variable de tipo XMLTYPE que contiene el XML completo, VL_C_ESPACIO es un VARCHAR2 que contiene el espacio de nombres del XML y  VL_XL_EVENTO es una variable del tipo XMLTYPE en la que se almacena el nodo que hemos extraído.

A ver si con esto te vale.

Comment: Hola @Xtin9 , no entendi que seria vl_c_espacio, me pones el ejemplo sobre mi xml de "espacio de nombre", por favor? Gracias! 
PD: agrego info... el xml me lo manda por parametro una app movile, lo tengo que procesar y bajando los datos a tablas, pero en este caso tengo que ir "subrecortando" el xml y mandalo a distintas funciones.

Comment: El espacio de nombre es un campo de los xml; el de la propiedad xmlns. Te paso un enlace para que veas de lo que te hablo.
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_de_nombres_XML